# Aliasing property names in derived class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, inheritance, properties, polymorphism

I am writing my own Vector class by inheriting from my own Point class.  The fields which I call x, y, and z in the Point class I would like to call i, j, and k in the Vector class.  The same private double variables back the properties.

The approach I am using is to declare x, y, and z as private in the Vector class and set up i, j, and k as public, but with the same get/setters, like so:

Will this work okay, or am I setting myself up for heartache?

```
public class ptsVector : ptsPoint
{
   private double x { get { return x_; } set { x_ = value; } }
   private double y { get { return y_; } set { y_ = value; } }
   private double z { get { return z_; } set { z_ = value; } }

   public double i { get { return x_; } set { x_ = value; } }
   public double j { get { return y_; } set { y_ = value; } }
   public double k { get { return z_; } set { z_ = value; } }
   // methods elided for clarity
}
```

Note that the Point class has x_, y_, and z_ as protected doubles.

Comment: Will technically work fine, but its a bit confusing. If I was developing and using this class I would be frustrated that there are 2 property setters setting the same variable.

Comment: Is there another (preferred) way to alias a property name?

Comment: Why do you reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Personally if you want 2 names for the same thing, make them both getters and create a method to set the value that isnt tightly coupled to either name, ie create a DefineVector(x,y,z) or something.

Comment: @lukas: I am not sure what you are talking about.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.vector.aspx is a 2d vector.  I need a 3d vector.

Comment: you can reference to other dll say http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx or include existing source code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17425/A-Vector-Type-for-C

Comment: Okay, so I found System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D and System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D.  Now I am doing it for the sheer joy of learning :).  I may refactor my stuff to use Microsoft's one day, but hey, see what I learned this evening by trying to bake my own?  I think it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need more info on how you are going to use these. If you don't need to refer to a ptsVector as a ptsPoint, then I would ditch the inheritance. Can you say a vector *is a* point? If not, then polymorphism is not appropriate here.

This particular example aside, I think aliasing a property is a Bad Idea, no matter what. It adds lots of complexity for no real benefit.

Comment: Can you say a vector is a point?  In some ways, yes, and in other ways, no.  It just has its three components, just like a Point.  But you can't dot-product and cross-product Points, just Vectors.  If you subtract one Point from another you get a Vector.  So, like I said, from a software development standpoint, the line defining that is fuzzy.  But literature on vectors refers to i, j, and k, so I want to stay consistent with that.

Comment: I say break the relationship, and develop the classes separately. If, in the future, you find lots of duplicated functionality, then you can try to bring the common code into a common base class.

Comment: I agree, vector != point even if they have the same properties

Comment: Advice Taken -- dropping the inheritance relationship.  I think my first occurence of heartache would be when I tried to put this in my point class:  public ptsVector subtract(ptsPoint otherPt){...}

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid doing this:  just from a semantic standpoint, they are two different concepts and one doesn't really "inherit" the other.  If anything, I would say a *vector* **contains** two *points*, as it is defined as the path from point A to point B.

As you say, you're setting yourself up for heartache when you start to add functionality to the classes.  Any benefit you think you're deriving from this inheritance would best be pursued in a semantically correct way.

Comment: I think technically a vector is defined as the *dx, dy, dz* (as in this case), providing two points is a path, vectors are origin independant, ie a vector will always be the path between (0,0,0) and (x,y,z)